# Extending (not overwriting) pan gesture of a UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, extend, uipangesturerecognizer, panning

well...the title says it all...i have a UIScrollView as a subview of the main UIView ... i'd like the UIViewController to act on the behalf of the UIScrollView when panning, but without overwriting the panning implementation of the UIScrollView.

Comment: In the absence of further information, "act on behalf of" and "without overriding" are contradictory.

Comment: i was trying to say that i would like to make the panning gesture to do more than just panning (hiding some views when i begin panning)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `UIViewController` to be the `delegate` of your `UIScrollView`, and hide the views from within the delegate method `-scrollViewDidScroll:`.